# QR code generation programmatically

Tags: objective-c, iphone, qr-code

In my application I need to generated a QR code and I have to scan it to get the result which is contained in the QR code. I have implemented the QR code scanning using ZBAR SDK but I cannot generate a QR code. I have tried to use ZXING but it is not working. Please suggest any SDK or or any link which I can go through to implement it. I have tried this link

https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Answer (score 1):

Use `CIFilter` to generate QR code.

```
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];

[filter setDefaults];

NSData *data = [url dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[filter setValue:data forKey:@"inputMessage"];

CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
```

See: https://github.com/shu223/iOS7-Sampler/blob/master/iOS7Sampler/SampleViewControllers/QRCodeViewController.m

Comment: Thank you.I have implemented it successfully.Can I customise the QR code image according to my own will?

Comment: You can use `[UIImage drawInRect:]` to draw a customized QR code image. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/